# Flex box not working

Tags: html, css, meteor, flexbox, material-design-lite

I am developing a web app with meteor and material design lite.

Here is what I want to do :

[image]

Here is the result with a too small window :

[image]

And here is the result with a bigger window :

[image]

The HTML code :

```
<template name="myRefrigerator_header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">My Refrigerator</span>
      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Simple Textfield -->
    <div id="msg-layout">
      <form action="#">
        <div  class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield" id="msg-layout-content">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="content">
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1">Text...</label>
        </div>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--primary"
          id="msg-layout-add-button">
          Enregistrer
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

And the CSS applied to it :

```
#msg-layout {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  margin: 0px 25px 15px 25px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#msg-layout-content {
  color: #3F51B5;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

#msg-layout-add-button {
}
```

I don't understand why I don't have the right behavior, I have specified that I only want one row and that my input should resize.

What am I getting wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to give the `id="msg-layout"` to the `<form>`. Only direct children of a `display:flex` layout will get the special attributes of flexible containers. You are negating flexbox by nesting a `<form>` where the flexible children would be. Your flexible layout only has one child, the `<form>`.

This is the best resource I have found for learning flex-box https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trimming things down. Flex-box isn't the problem, and more that libraries of style rules make a lot of assumptions - that you may not be able to see from the top.

Here is a stripped down version / http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/MKzMgp

HTML

```
<form class='this-form' action='#'>
    <label class='input-w' for='sample1'>
        <input type='text' id='sample1'>
        <span>Text...</span>
    </label>
    <button>Enregistrer</button>
</form>
```

SCSS

```
* { // reset box model
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.this-form {
    display: flex; // a
    flex-direction: row; // b
    align-items: center; // d
    max-width: 24rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    .input-w {
        position: relative;
        flex-grow: 1; // c 
        input {
            width: 100%;
            border: 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
            &:focus {
                outline: none;
                + span {
                    transform: translate(0, -50px);
                    opacity: 0;
                }   
            }
        }
        span {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 3px;
            left: 0;
            color: gray;
            font-size: 12px;
            transition: 1s;
        }
    }
    button {
        height: 30px;
        background: transparent;
        border: 0;
        color: blue;
        margin-left: .5rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mdl-textfield__input` class has a set width of 300px due to animation limitations. You need to override this (say `width: 100%`) to get an expandable textfield. However, this may have adverse affects on the animations since CSS animations don't like unknown lengths.

Comment: As soon as you use `width:blah` you are negating the benefits of `flex-direction:row{-reverse}`. Use `flex-basis:blah` so flexbox can do it's job. You only use `width:blah` if you have `flex-direction:column{-reverse}`.

Comment: They are wondering why the input width isn't expanding, that is why. However, I did provide the wrong target, fixing that now.

Comment: If you want the input to grow, just add the attribute: `flex-grow: 1`. This will make the input fill the rest of the available space. If your other elements are shrinking from this, give them `flex-shrink: 0;flex-basis:{MIN_WIDTH px/em/vw/%...};`